# On click take location data and display on google map

Tags: jquery, json

I have a list of fake addresses which is populated through a data.json file. Each of these addresses has a lat and long position.

How would I go about writing an on click function to read the lat and long position of that address?

Currently, when a user enters their postcode the first address lat and long position is displayed in the google map.

jquery

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m', function(data) {
            //console.log('json')
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             if (value.address.postcode.search(expression) != -1) {
                    //console.log(value)
                    //COURIER ADDRESS DETAILS
                $('#result').append('<li data-contentid="' + key + '" 
                                         class="list-group-item courier">
                                      <div class="c-image mr-3">
                                       <img src="../images/hermes-logo.jpg" class="w-100">
                                      </div><div class="result-address">
                                      <div class="c-name font-weight-bold">
                                           ' + value.name + ' 
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="address">
                                         ' + value.address.name + ',
                                         ' + value.address.line1 + ',
                                         ' + value.address.town + ',
                                         ' + value.address.county + ',
                                         ' + value.address.postcode + '
                                      </div>
                               </div>
                         </li>');

             var mapProp = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                                          value.location.latitude, 
                                          value.location.longitude),
                          zoom: 5,
                       };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(
                                       document.getElementById("googleMap"), 
                                       mapProp);
           var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                       value.location.latitude,
                                       value.location.longitude);
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                       position: myLatlng,
                                       title:"Hello World!"
                          });
                    marker.setMap(map);

                }
            });

        });
```

any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Note that creating new map inside each iteration of loop doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, do you know how I should go about it? thanks

Comment: Create the map once either on page load or before the loop